# Toggle between open Tabs in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, browser-tabs

I have multiple tabs open in IE 8 (OS is Windows 7 Home Premium). Let us name the tabs as T1, T2, T3, ... , T7

I am currently on T7. What do I do if I want to toggle between Tab T4 and T7?

Alt  + Tab - Switches between different apps that are open. 
Ctrl + Tab - Cycles through the different tabs that are open in the current Window. What I want is something like we have in Visual Studio.

Irrespective of how the documents are opened, a Ctrl + Tab always toggles between the last two files opened.

Is it possible in IE 8.0?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, but there are these keyboard shortcuts:

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> = Switch to the right tab

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> = Switch to the left tab

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>*n*</kbd> = Switch to a specific tab number

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd> = Switch to the last tab

[Source](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Internet-Explorer-8-keyboard-shortcuts)

You can most probably do it using [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) or [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/index.shtml) (you may like the second one better if you are a programmer).